# Algebra - endomorphisms of field

Tags: ring-homomorphism

Find all endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}$. ($\mathbb{Q}$ is the field.)

When finding isomorphism of $2\mathbb{Z}$ and $3\mathbb{Z}$, we define the mapping like $φ: 2\mathbb{Z} → 3\mathbb{Z}$ and then we say $φ(2) = 3k, k∈Z$.

How to start in this case of $\mathbb{Q}$? Can you just tell me how does the mapping look like? Thanks for your time!

Comment: It looks just like the identity map.

Comment: Like φ (k) = k ?

Comment: Yes, just like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is different if we are looking for ring endomorphisms or group endomorphisms.

Let's start with ring endomorphisms, as they are easier. Suppose $\phi : \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is a ring homomorphism. Then $$\phi(q) = q\phi(1) = q$$ for any $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and hence $\phi$ is just the identity. Therefore $\{\textrm{ring endomorphisms of } \mathbb{Q}\} \cong \{\textrm{id}\}$.

Now suppose $\phi : \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is a group homorphism. For any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, we have $$\phi(nq) = \phi(q + \cdots + q) = \phi(q) + \cdots +\phi(q) = n\phi(q)$$ Therefore if $q = \frac{m}{n}$ is a fraction, $n\phi(q) = \phi(m)$ so $$\phi(q) = \frac{\phi(m)}{n} = \frac{m}{n}\phi(1)$$ Hence, $\phi$ is determined by $\phi(1)$. Since $\phi(1)$ can take any value in $\mathbb{Q}$, and each homomorphism is distinct, we obtain a (ring) isomorphism:

$$ \begin{align} \{\textrm{group endomorphisms of } \mathbb{Q}\} & \rightarrow \mathbb{Q} \\ \phi & \mapsto \phi(1)\end{align}$$

and so $\{\textrm{group endomorphisms of } \mathbb{Q}\}\cong \mathbb{Q}$.

This example shows it is always important to be precise which category we are working over!

Comment: Thank you so much!